# Check validation of single v-text-field on vuetify 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a component holding v-text-field input.
On vue2 with vuetify 2, I was able to control the background of the input like this

The html

```
<v-text-field
  :background-color="setInputBgColor()"
  ref="input"
  :disabled="disabled"
  v-model="inputValue"
  @blur="validateInput()"
  :rules="[required]"
>
</v-text-field>
```

And the setInputBgColor function:

```js
setInputBgColor () {
  if (this.error || (this.$refs.input && !this.$refs.input.valid)) {
    return '#FCDFDF'
  }
    return '#F4F4F4'
  },
```

So, with `this.$refs.input.valid` I was able to control if the input was not valid according to the rules

In Vue3 i have updated the HTML according to vuetify3 (basically change prop to bg-color):

```html
<v-text-field
  :bg-color="setInputBgColor()"
  ref="input"
  v-model="inputValue"
  @blur="validateInput()"
  :rules="[required]"
>
</v-text-field>
```

But the `this.$refs.input.valid` is not longer working, and I can't find a proper way to do it.
Is there any alternative to `this.$refs.input.valid`?

After some investigation I found that apparently you still can use it with async/await, something like `const valid = await this.$refs.input.validate();` but this does not work to set the background color, because

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "bgColor". Expected String with value "[object Promise]", got Promise.

Any hint or alternative? I don't know what i am doing wrong, and the only way I can think of achieving similar functionality to what I had in Vue 2 is by manually handling when the rules are not met.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no replacement as far as I know for the `valid()` function on the individual component.  VForm I believe provides more granular validation techniques, specifically with vee-validate... but looking at your specific problem, you could solve it with regular CSS stylings as a workaround:

```css
<style scoped>
  .v-text-field :deep(.v-field) {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .v-text-field :deep(.v-field--error) {
    background-color: #fcdfdf;
  }
</style>
```

[Vuetify Playground demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9kE1ugzAUhK/y4i6SSgFUhaoSJZF6iW5CFi5+NFaM7fqHUiW5ew0USDcRCzzj5/E33p+JNWXypnXceCQZyR3WWlCHu0IC5E1k0GolLW8QSkGt3RakbiPqnSoI1LSNvjlzx+Bu0rQg/SkIk7w8gZJQcRRsDe6IcjS9s5zhMBfyHbYu6sfAYBVyuNTehewmqhVDMTrvVHgMdma8wI5ib/DLc4PsMF2bJ7d5Q4NgzRWClSc3DYO0peHa9bPYamUcMKyoFw7OQyijjq4eRwWB0nkjZw0w82WwXK7njZEwgwa2O1gsGrhcYDm05XbahxWVDKz7EWEd9OJxTrkOi2tvBJEnE3FH350BWyqNQ9/434tmDFGvgtfLqcQHLU+fRnnJolIJZTJ4qNLue/275H5OFKExytyNK1nFqjEuMHecAZBc12QTp/EL6f7P8RM5/AKYp9GM)

Comment: That really solve my problem with the background color. Thanks!